# MySql Query Slow On Very Large Table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with 85,000 records, which will grow daily!

I am running a query for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`  
WHERE `start_timestamp` >= 'TIMESTAMP'  
AND `end_timestamp` <= 'TIMESTAMP'
```

This query is literally taking forever to run on 85,000 rows, never mind 1,000,000

Now the field for the timestamp is actually a large integer holding a timestamp from php. The query is run through php with codeigniter query()

It runs pretty quick if the date range < 31 days, but anything above that it's extremely slow. I also have indexes on those 2 columns on the where clause.

Comment: what is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_timestamp >= 'TIMESTAMP' AND end_timestamp <= 'TIMESTAMP'`

Comment: i don't have the time to run that query at the moment, i will update on monday. In all my years developing web applications i have never had a query run this slow, especially when the columns are indexed

Comment: You mean to say that your column(s) is an int? My guess is that PHP/SQL have to constantly calculate and reformat to a proper time format. Why not set your column(s) as DATETIME or similar type?

Comment: it was just as slow using DATETIME . I don't think it is the query actually, i think somewhere in the php is causing it to be slow. If i run an example query in SQLyog it runs very quickly.

Comment: ahhh sorry it's me having a dumb Friday! It's the php generating the wrong query

Comment: `Another happy ending`

Answer (score 2):

These are some suggestions to improve the performance of the query

1. Replace SELECT * by the only fields you want
2. Add indexing on the table fields you want as output
3. Apply LIMIT tag as and when required. Don't select all the records
4. Fire two different queries: one for counting total number of records and other for fetching number of records per page (e.g. 10, 20, 50, etc...)
5. If applicable, create Database Views and get data from them instead of tables

Answer (score 1):

Since `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` are the only criteria for your query, I suggest you create an index for them.

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_timestamp` ON `table` (`start_timestamp`, `end_timestamp`);
```

This should optimize MySQL's ability to locate the records with the specified criteria.